# is there a "best way" to short circuit a mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, short-circuiting

I have a situation where I'm assembling a query based on user provided criteria and want to figure out what the most efficient way is to do this.

If I have a table that looks like this:

```
int id | varchar phone | varchar email | varchar RFID
```

and the user will pass in an array which defines the order (and items) with which they'd like to look up a user which *could look like this:

```
["id","email","phone"]
```

or it could look like this:

```
["email"]
```

or it could look like this:

```
["phone","rfid"]
```

or any other possible combination of those 4 fields.

Based on what I receive I need to look the user up in the order in which these fields arrived and if I find a match, I don't want to keep looking.

In other words if the input is

```
["email","rfid","phone"]
```

and I look into the db and find a user with the provided email, I don't want to keep looking to see if their rfid also matches, I just want to return said user.
However, if I don't find such an email, then I want to move on to the rfid.

So, in the various tests I've done (mostly playing with a `case` statement in the `where` clause) my results have been really terrible.  Frequently taking almost a second to return a value, as opposed to taking <50ms when I simplify the `where` to search for the individual field.

I should note that all these fields are indexed.

So... my question is, should I just bite the bullet and make as many sql calls as there are items in the incoming array, or is there some really efficient way to structure a single query that will not bog down the system as my various attempts have.

I recognize that this may be too abstract a question, but am hoping that there's some mechanism for just such a use that I'm simply overlooking.

Comment: it would probably be best to do them as separate queries. Search for the first field; if it doesn't find anything, search for the second field, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any good way to do a short-circuit in SQL. You can construct a `WHERE` clause that uses `OR` to combine the critiera, but doing this generally prevents it from using the indexes. You can use a `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 1 precedence, table.*
     FROM table
     WHERE field1 = 'value'
     UNION
     SELECT 2 precedence, table.*
     FROM table
     WHERE field2 = 'value'
     ...
    ) x
ORDER BY precedence
LIMIT 1
```

where you replace `field1`, `field2`, etc. with the field names from the input array. This will produce the desired results in one query, but it will have to perform all the sub-queries, it won't short-circuit.

The best solution is probably to solve it in the application code. Loop through the fields in the input, and perform a query for just that field. When you get a result, break out of the loop and return it.

Comment: yeah, that's what I concluded as well... just thought maybe I was overlooking something more elegant.  On the whole, I'm still unclear on what sort of performance hit I take on running multiple queries vs. constructing elaborate single query solutions.  I get the sense that it's actually pretty harmless (and indeed preferred) to just run several simple queries, vs. one convoluted one.